# How can I make vegan jerky?

Tags: protein, recipe-request, meat-substitutes

How can I make a vegan jerky?

I've seen some vegan jerky at the store, but it's *very* expensive and a lot of plastic waste.

How can I make my own vegan jerky at home?

Comment: See also https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/38/what-is-seitan-how-do-i-get-it

Answer (score 2):

### Vegan Jerky

It has been at least 55 years since I tasted beef jerky.

You may be able to get a similar texture using textured vegetable protein (TVP) chunks.

Add just enough water, oil, and seasoning mix to make the TVP flexible.

Fry the TVP chunks over medium heat while occasionally pressing with a spatula.

Seasoning may include soy sauce, Worcestershire sauce*, liquid smoke, brown sugar, salt, pepper, meat tenderizer, garlic powder, onion powder, and paprika.

I add something similar to fried rice, chow mein, etc., and end up snacking on the bits while cooking.

- Worcestershire sauce may contain anchovies, read the label.